# WebGL: Failing at drawing points: glDrawArrays: "attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1"

Tags: javascript, web, buffer, webgl, point-clouds

I am trying to display points (a pointcloud actually) using WebGL. The past 2 days I spent going through [this](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217) tutorial and still have a lot of my code based on it.

I am attempting to load a .ply file and then show each coordinate as a coloured point, but get stuck at this error when trying to draw it:

`[.WebGLRenderingContext-0x111ff17bc300]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1`

I have of course done some research, but the general answer was that the length of the buffered arrays would be different, which I have made sure is not the case. It's mostly likely a similar noobish mistake though:

```
function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }
        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }
        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }
        return shader;
    }
    var shaderProgram;
    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var mvMatrixStack = [];
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function mvPushMatrix() {
        var copy = mat4.create();
        mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
        mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
    }

    function mvPopMatrix() {
        if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
            throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
        }
        mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    }

    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }


    var pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer;
    var pointcloudColourBuffer;
    var pointcloudIndexBuffer;
    function handlePoints(pointCoords, pointColours, indices) {
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pointCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = pointCoords.length / 3;

        pointcloudColourBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudColourBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pointColours), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudColourBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        pointcloudColourBuffer.numItems = pointColours.length / 3;

        pointcloudIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudIndexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
        pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems = indices.length;
    }

    var coordList = [];
    var colList = [];
    var indexList = [];
    function loadPLY(){
        jQuery.get('some_ascii.ply', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            var coords = false;

            for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
                if (coords) {
                    var splitString = lines[line].split(" ");
                    coordList.push(parseFloat(splitString[0]), parseFloat(splitString[1]), parseFloat(splitString[2]));
                    colList.push(parseFloat(splitString[3]), parseFloat(splitString[4]), parseFloat(splitString[5]));
                    indexList.push(parseFloat(line));
                }
                else{
                    if (lines[line] == "end_header"){
                        console.log("end header");
                        coords = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            handlePoints(coordList, colList, indexList);
        });
    }

    function drawScene(){
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        //mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -6]);

        //gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudColourBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, pointcloudColourBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        setMatrixUniforms();
        //gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        //console.log("1", pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems);
        //console.log("2", pointcloudColourBuffer.numItems);
        //console.log("3", pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }


    function tick() {
        requestAnimFrame(tick);
        drawScene();
    }

    function webGLStart(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        loadPLY();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        tick();
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete runnable example? Its hard to debug just from looking at your code, especially since most of it is just copy paste from the tutorial. I suspect tho, "attribute 1" refers to `pointColours` and something is off there.

Comment: Quickly put everything used on some server. There you go:


http://sunshin.0xhost.net/PointsTest2.html


http://sunshin.0xhost.net/webgl-utils.js


http://sunshin.0xhost.net/glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js


http://sunshin.0xhost.net/untitled.ply

Comment: I think you need to change `jQuery.get('eule_small_color_ascii.ply')` in your code to `'sunshin.0xhost.net/untitled.ply'`

Comment: Sorry, that was another example that I didn't change yet. Changed it in the code I linked, thanks!

Comment: Ok i think the problem is this line: `gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);     
`shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute` is undefined, did you mean `shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute` ?

Comment: I think I got mislead by just comparing the length of the array and then assuming it all got parsed right. At the end of the .ply file there are values that aren't just coordinates and colours (to generate the mesh, I guess). The error disappeared after a simple dirty fix (if length of split string != 6 then coords = false). New error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemSize' of undefined` in drawScene when trying to access this property for the first time.

Comment: And thanks, I completely overlooked that. I replaced the link to the main file with my current version and fixed parsing and renamed the shaderprogram.x :) Now time to fix that itemSize bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through your code again and I noticed a couple things:

If you are drawing gl.POINT you need to include `gl_PointSize = 8.0;` in your vertex shader, else the points wouldnt be drawn.

Your color data is incorrect. Negative colors does not make sense.

Your drawArrays call is incorrect, should be `gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems);`

I disabled perspective because it is hard to tell without a camera to know if the things are being drawn correctly, but out of view.

The `Cannot read property 'itemSize' of undefined` you mentioned is because it is attempting to draw the scene before your .ply data is parsed. To fix, only start drawing when parsing is complete.

So here is my edited version which, at least, draws (you have to change the src):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<script type="text/javascript" src="aaa/glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aaa/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        //gl_FragColor = vColor;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec4 aVertexColor;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec4 vColor;

    void main(void) {
        gl_PointSize = 8.0;
        //gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vColor = aVertexColor;
    }

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var gl;
    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }
    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }
        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }
        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }
        return shader;
    }
    var shaderProgram;
    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");

        console.log(shaderProgram);
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var mvMatrixStack = [];
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function mvPushMatrix() {
        var copy = mat4.create();
        mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
        mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
    }

    function mvPopMatrix() {
        if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
            throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
        }
        mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
    }

    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }

    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
    }


    var pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer;
    var pointcloudColourBuffer;
    var pointcloudIndexBuffer;
    function handlePoints(pointCoords, pointColours, indices) {
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pointCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = pointCoords.length / 3;

        pointcloudColourBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudColourBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(pointColours), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudColourBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        pointcloudColourBuffer.numItems = pointColours.length / 3;

        pointcloudIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudIndexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        pointcloudIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
        pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems = indices.length;
    }

    var coordList = [];
    var colList = [];
    var indexList = [];
    function loadPLY(){
        jQuery.get('aaa/untitled.ply', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            var coords = false;

            for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
                if (coords) {
                    var splitString = lines[line].split(" ");
                    if (splitString.length === 6) {
                        coordList.push(parseFloat(splitString[0]), parseFloat(splitString[1]), parseFloat(splitString[2]));
                        colList.push(parseFloat(splitString[3]), parseFloat(splitString[4]), parseFloat(splitString[5]));
                        indexList.push(parseFloat(line));
                    }
                    else{
                        coords = false;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (lines[line].indexOf("end_header")===0){
                        console.log("end header");
                        coords = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            handlePoints(coordList, colList, indexList);
            tick();
        });

    }

    function drawScene(){
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        //mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -6]);

        //gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudColourBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, pointcloudColourBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        setMatrixUniforms();
        //gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
        //console.log("1", pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems);
        //console.log("2", pointcloudColourBuffer.numItems);
        //console.log("3", pointcloudVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, pointcloudIndexBuffer.numItems);
    }


    function tick() {
        requestAnimFrame(tick);
        drawScene();
    }

    function webGLStart(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        loadPLY();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    }


</script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
    #loadingtext {
        position:absolute;
        top:250px;
        left:150px;
        font-size:2em;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<body onload="webGLStart();">
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, thanks a lot! I figured out earlier where the itemSize error is coming from (not waiting for it being parsed), but forgot about it when I fixed the other error later.

The negative colours: I really need more sleep (and breaks) when coding.. I think Blender exported .ply's don't even have colours, I will look into that again. I hope with proper values it should be fine.

The drawArrays call: I added some parameters that drawElements uses and hoped it changes something. Would have been much smarter to look into what the parameters actually mean.

Thanks a lot!